# Is the syntax of loops in C different than C#?

Tags: c

Just started learning C for Unix programming. I have this function snippet

```
void print_bits(unsigned int x)
{
    int mask = 0x80000000 //1 in biggest sigfig

    //store string or whatever
    while(mask>0){
        /* code */
        

        >>mask;
    }
    

}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and the line `while(mask>0){` gives me a missing semicolon error. Is this an issue with my IDE or is there somewhere I'm supposed to be putting a semicolon in this loop? Logically it doesn't seem like there should be another semicolon in this snippet.

Attempted to put a loop inside of a function, resulted in a missing token error. Expected a functioning function body.

Comment: Your missing semicolon is in `int mask = 0x80000000`.

Comment: `>>mask;` is wrong too. You likely want `mask >>= 1;` aka `mask = mask >> 1;`.

Comment: You're attempting to set the sign bit of a signed integer (`mask`), Then, it seems, performing right shifts on that variable. I'm pretty sure this will result in Undefined Behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon error you get is from the previous line, not the while line.

```
int mask = 0x80000000 //1 in biggest sigfig
```

needs to become

```
int mask = 0x80000000; //1 in biggest sigfig
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice this because the error was always showing on the wrong line.